# Writing and reading from a file and sort them in ascending order

Tags: c, file-io, fgets, scanf, bubble-sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sort(int *p, int size)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j)
    {
      if (p[j] > p[j + 1])
      {
        int temp;
        temp = p[j];
        p[j] = p[j + 1];
        p[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

void createtestfile()
{
  FILE *f1;
  f1 = fopen("program.txt", "w");
  fprintf(f1, "6#this is comment\n");
  fprintf(f1, "3#this is comment\n");
  fprintf(f1, "7#this is comment\n");
  fprintf(f1, "2\n");
}

void readtestfile()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buff[1024];
  int value;

  int number_of_lines;
  fp = fopen("program.txt", "r");
  do
  {
    fgets(buff, 1024, fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);
    number_of_lines++;
    buff[number_of_lines] = value;
  } while (fp != EOF);

  sort(buff, number_of_lines);

  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < number_of_lines; i++)
  {
    printf("value is %d", buff[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  createtestfile();
  readtestfile();
  return 0;
}
```

I am writing a string to a file. Later reading only integers from a file and sort them in ascending order. I am using fgets to reading a line by line from the file and I have problem in reading only integers from a file.

Comment: Output : it's not displaying any numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to close the file after having written to it.

Due to this the content most propably will be written when the application end, because to the then will be clsoed implicitly.

Add

```
fclose(f1)
```

after the last `fprintf()` in `createtestfile()`.

---

Secondly when reading from the file you should decide whether to use `fgets()` of `fscanf()` to read in the data.

Or you can switch from reading from the file directly using `fscanf()` to do a `sscanf()` from the "string" you read using `fgets()`.

To do so replace

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);
```

with

```
sscanf(buff, "%d", &value);
```

---

Thirdly it makes no sense to try to write what you scanned in from `buff` back to `buff`, at least because you are overwriting `buff` in the next round of the read-loop.

Also you pass `buff` to `sort()` which should make the compiler yell out a loud warning.

Initialise the loop counter `number_of_lines` properly to `0`and use an integer array to store the values you scanned out of the file's content. This you then can pass into `sort()`.

Comment: I closed in both readtestfile() and createtestfile () but then also it's not showing any output.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` is consuming line, you have to use `sscanf` instead of `fscanf` after `fgets`

```
  do
  {
    fgets(buff, 1024, fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &value); /* here */
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your knowledge, you can sort your data by using the inbuilt sort function qsort.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* qsort */

int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<6; n++)
     printf ("%d ",values[n]);
  return 0;
}
```